# android fragment control main activity

Tags: java, android, variables, android-fragments

I have my app working with fragment called into the main activity. Everything works great but i would like to be able to control the menu above the fragment layout.

So lets say you navigate to fragment blog posts i would like to the text view i set in the menu above the fragment to update or hide a button or show a button with set visibility.

I have no clue how to control the things who are not in the current fragment.

How should i go about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Define an interface in your fragment and have your Activity implement that interface.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    // add methods here
}
```

In onAttach, get the interface:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceof MyInterface) {
        mMyInterface = (MyInterface) activity;
    } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity + " must implement interface MyInterface");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    mMyInterface = null;
    super.onDetach();
}
```

Then simply call mMyInterface methods as needed.

Comment: but how should i call it from the activity. something mMyInterface.Button.set visibility or something like that. I am pretty new to android.

Comment: You could tell the activity what the fragment has done (onShowBlogPost) and let the Activity decide what to do with the UI on that event. The fragmente should know nothing about the activity other than the interface.

Comment: I have solved it by using the following code MainActivity mainActivity;mainActivity.musicButton.setVisibility(View.GONE); Thank for the help Francesc.